# Can not use R class of library project

Tags: android, eclipse, library-project

I have a library project A: `package com.a`

And I have another project B: `package com.b`

In project B, I use `com.a.R.xxx`.  <== **It is OK**.

But when I set project B is library project, Eclipse said

> "com.a.R.xxx cannot be resolved to a variable".

I don't understand why Eclipse cannot find `com.a.R` if B is a library project. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please give me a comment instead of down vote this question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common bug.
Possible solutions include:

- Clean projects and rebuild
- There is an error in an xml file (or that specific one) that is preventing the file from being loaded properly
- Android Developer tools are out of date. Run an update in the SDK manager and eclipse plugin

Comment: 1. Of course, I clean and rebuild many times before asking here.

2. There is no error in any xml file. I'm sure because this error only happends when I set B is library project.

3. Ok, I will update everything (although I've just downloaded new ADT few days ago).